# Firebase Custom Dimensions that are boolean don't show up in graphs

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an event called "walkthru" with a parameter that is called "boolean" and it is sent as true or false.

I added the custom dimension called "boolean" so that it would appear in the Graphs Reports of the event.
But after waiting for weeks.. the never showed up. Other custom dimensions work fine, but this one doesnt, and I can see the values 0 or 1 in the LiveView of the event.

Any idea why ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried updating your boolean as Strings or numbers?

Comment: @AmodGokhale thats what Im doing now.. I called BooleanString, will see if it reflects.

Comment: Bit late to the discussion, but did this work @omarojo to change the boolean to a "true" or "false" string?